# Simplest way to unwrap an option and return Error if None (Anyhow)

Tags: rust, error-handling

I'm using [Anyhow](https://docs.rs/anyhow) and have a function that returns `anyhow::Result`. In that function I want to "unwrap" an option so that if the option value is `None`, an error with a specific error message to be returned. That's what I've done:

```
let o: Option<i32> = ...;
let v: i32 = o.ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("Oh, boy!"))?;
// here I need v only
```

I've used `ok_or_else()` instead of `ok_or()` for performance reasons.

I'm generally fine with that but was wondering if that's the simplest (most concise) way to do what I want (w/o sacrificing performance)?

Comment: I would say that is good.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should use [`context`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.44/anyhow/trait.Context.html#tymethod.context) ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4fb2c6fc831c56a4aaca2a8ae181fbf0)):

```rust
use anyhow::{Context, Result};

fn _foo(o: Option<i32>) -> Result<i32> {
    let v = o.context("Oh, boy!")?;
    Ok(v)
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I find this `context` name a bit cryptic..

Answer (score 7):

This question has been gaining popularity, so I decided, as an addition to eggyal's answer, to describe how the [`context()`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.71/anyhow/trait.Context.html#tymethod.context) method actually works "under the hood", so that it can be conveniently used on an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) value like this: `some_opt.context("some error info here")?`.

---

### `context()`

First, [anyhow](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow) exposes a public trait [`Context`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.71/anyhow/trait.Context.html) that has a method `context()`:

```
pub trait Context<T, E>: Sealed {
    fn context<C>(self, context: C) -> Result<T, Error>
       where C: Display + Send + Sync + 'static;
```

That `Context` trait is implemented for [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) and the [implementation](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.71/src/anyhow/context.rs.html#91-101) looks like this:

```
impl<T> Context<T, Infallible> for Option<T> {
    fn context<C>(self, context: C) -> Result<T, Error>
    where
        C: Display + Send + Sync + 'static,
    {
        match self {
            Some(ok) => Ok(ok),
            None => Err(Error::from_display(context, backtrace!())),
        }
    }
```

The implementation of the internal [`from_display()`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.71/src/anyhow/error.rs.html#136-160) is a bit more convoluted. It makes use of the unsafe [`Error::construct()`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.71/src/anyhow/error.rs.html#222-243) and returns an [`anyhow::Error`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/struct.Error.html) value.

---

### `with_context()`

`Context` also defines a similar method [`with_context()`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.71/src/anyhow/lib.rs.html#609-612), that can be used to provide context that is evaluated *lazily* (only when an error actually occurs). Example:

```
some_opt.with_context(|| format!("User {u} has no money"))?
```

Apart from the "laziness", the [implementation](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.71/src/anyhow/context.rs.html#103-112) of `with_context()` is essentially the same as the implementation of `context()`.

---

### Comparison with `ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("..."))`

It might be worth noting that in the stack (back)trace that `anyhow` generates (when using *nightly* or `features = ["backtrace"]`), if we use the expression `ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("..."))`, there will be one extra element on top, looking like this:

```
Stack backtrace:
   0: anyhow::error::<impl anyhow::Error>::msg
```

The same happens if we use [`bail!`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/macro.bail.html) or [`ensure!`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/macro.ensure.html), for example.

When we use `context()` or `context_with()`, there is no such line in the stack trace.