# Is there a less verbose way to extract values from Options in Rust

Tags: rust

I find myself doing something like the following a lot:

```
fn foo() -> Result<i32, String> {
    let cur = match something_that_returns_an_option() {
        Some(cur) => cur,
        None => return Err("Some error"),
    };
    
    // use `cur`
    
    1
}
```

If I need several variables, I'm left with this pattern over and over again, or nested if lets/matches.

I there a more ergonomic way to handle repeatedly extracting values from Options?

Comment: See [A shortcut for propagating errors: The `?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator) in the Rust book.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue if the function returns a `Result`. I updated my question to make that more obvious.

Comment: That edit is helpful. You might be in write-a-macro territory here, but I'm a relative newcomer so there are likely to be approaches I don't know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for [`Option::ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or). It lets you map an `Option` into a `Result` with the provided error. Combined with the `?` operator you clean things up nicely:

```rust
fn foo() -> Result<i32, String> {
    let cur = something_that_returns_an_option().ok_or("some error")?;
        
    Ok(cur + 1)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e8456378ad5dfe98bd0104431d59b5fd)

[`Option::ok_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or_else) might also be helpful,  as it evaluates the error branch lazily.

Comment: That much cleaner. Thanks! What if I want to `return Ok(1)` in the `None` case instead?

Comment: @marcantonio I don't think rust has a good way to do that, although `Option::unwrap_or` might be of interest depending on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @marcantonio: If you want custom logic, then `let cur = if let Some(v) = something_that_returns_an_option() { v } else { return Ok(1) };` is for now the shortest on stable, I am afraid. As mentioned, on Nightly there's `let Some(cur) = something_that_returns_an_option() else { return Ok(1) };` which is shorter.

Answer (score 7):

In your example you want to not just continue, break or return a regular value, but return an error. For that particular case, the Aiden4's answer is the way to go. Or, if you are using [anyhow](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/), you should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738600/simplest-way-to-unwrap-an-option-and-return-error-if-none-anyhow).

But I've been in situations where I want to unwrap or (in the case of `None`) directly `continue`, `break` or `return` a non-error value.

## Update (Rust 1.65+)

### let-else

The [let-else](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/let_else.html) feature was stabilized in Rust 1.65. Here is an example of how it can be used:

```
let options = vec![Some(74), None, Some(9)];
for o in options {
    let Some(v) = o else { continue };
    println!("v = {v}");
}
```

## Older answer (and alternative solutions)

Rust (still) doesn't provide a short and concise way to do exactly that.

Here is a "one-liner" which kinda does the trick, but is still a bit verbose:

```
let v = if let Some(d) = some_option_value { d } else { continue; };
```

If you want a shorter solution, here is something to consider...

### A macro

You can write a macro like this:

```
macro_rules! unwrap_or {
    ($e:expr, $or_do_what:expr) => {
        if let Some(d) = $e { d } else { $or_do_what }
    };
}
```

That will allow you to write code like this:

```
let options = vec![Some(74), None, Some(9)];
for o in options {
    let v = unwrap_or!(o, continue);
    // ...
}
```

That's a trivial example, but I think the biggest benefit can come if you need to perform multiple checks, so that instead of writing something "idiomatic" like this:

```
for thing in things {
    if let Some(a) = thing {
        // ...
        if let Some(b) = a.another_opt {
            // ...
            if let Some(c) = a.yet_another_opt {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

, you can simplify the code by avoiding the nesting of multiple blocks like this:

```
for thing in things {
    let a = unwrap_or!(thing, continue);
    // ...
    let b = unwrap_or!(a.another_opt, continue);
    // ...
    let c = unwrap_or!(a.yet_another_opt, continue);
    // ...
}
```

Whether that's a good practice is subjective, of course.

Comment: Note that the "one-liner" snippet is reformatted to no less than 5 lines by rustfmt with default settings. :(

Comment: @user4815162342 Good point. I use less-strict IDE settings in that regard, but even so, the "one-liner" isn't as easy on the eyes, as I would want it to be.

Comment: Thanks, this is good. The fact that one needs a macro here is what frustrates me about Rust. It makes me feel like I’m missing something fundamental.

Comment: @marcantonio you're not missing anything- this kind of pain point with error handling has been around for a while now. It led to the `?` operator, and will eventually lead to [try blocks.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html#try_blocks)

Comment: @marcantonio There is an RFC to make this built in: https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3137-let-else.html.